# Java executable command line

Tags: java, command, executable

I need to create an executable as a result of a Makefile. Something as simple as if the user types abc, followed by the required input, in the command line the program executes. The code was written in Java. 
My Makefile runs just fine but I am not sure of how to create that executable. 
The name of the main method is Main.java just in case is necessary

The full execution would be something like:

abc xxxx

Where xxxx is the user's input. I am getting NullPointers when reading the input. I have tried using `Scanner`, `BufferedReader`, and `System.console().system()` and  keep getting the same error.

Any advice on reading the input?

Thanks

Comment: GraalVM may be helpful: https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/aot-compilation/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `jar` command to convert a Java class to an executable:

`jar -cmf manifest.txt YourProgram.class`

Provided you have a `mainfest.txt` manifest file with at least this row:

`Main-Class: YourProgram`

Answer (score 0):

The right command once you compiled your program with javac is this:

```
jar cfn output.jar manifest.txt program.class
```

EDIT: The `n` option is deprecated, your can use `m` instead with no other change.

Where `output` is the name of your executable, `manifest` should contain at least one line:

```
Main-Class: program
```

and after that you can add as many classes as you need to.

Once you are done with that, the next step is to use some utility to convert the .jar to .exe . I recommend [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) since it is very easy to use and multi platform.

Comment: Could you explain what the `n` option does? I'm pretty sure you need to use `m` to use a manifest input file.

Comment: I believe it does the same thing, specifies that you want to use the classes written in the manifest.

Comment: You mean to say you didn't check before you posted this? I also don't think you can include the `.class` extension of the program entry classname in the manifest file. When you say "classes", do you mean to indicate that it's possible to specify **multiple** default program entry points?

Comment: No, I did checked, that's what it is used for. When I say classes I mean that you can add your own dependencies. For instance add `Class-Path: MyUtils.jar` as a way to include your own custom classes. And you are right, the .class extension is not required. As for the `m` option the syntax doesn't really change: `jar cfm output.jar manifest.txt program.class`. You can learn more about it here [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your command

```
abc xxxx
```

looks like one of these:

```
java Main xxxx
java -cp ... Main xxxx
java -jar ... xxxx
```

then you can access the second part `xxxx` like so:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main called with " + args);
    }
}
```

You cannot access the command line parameters on stdin or anywhere else, that is why your other attempts failed.